# Keystroke/hotkey/shortcut to expand Area/Iteration path in TFS?

Tags: excel, tfs, keyboard-shortcuts, workitem

I'm doing a lot of work with work items, and while I'm using Tfs 2010 aka VsAlm 2010, this has been something that's bugged me ever since the first release of Tfs. When creating new work items, I don't really want to switch back and forth between my mouse and keybaord 203948203984 times; I'd really much rather just enter it entirely sans-mouse using the keyboard. This is mostly possible, however the Area Path and Iteration Path fields present an obstacle, both from the Team Explorer client and in Excel.

This obstacle is that nothing I've tried will open up the treeview for arrow-key navigation. I would hope that this would function like other tree views, where up and down move up and down, and left/right perform expansion and collapse functions on nodes with children. However, nothing I've tried (enter, tab, space, ctrl-space, F2, etc) will open that up for me; and consequently I'm relegated to typing out the entire path or to switching to my mouse, which really slows me down at times.

Is there something I'm missing? Hard-core, veteran TFS users: is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>.

Comment: Like every other drop down list in Windows.

Comment: Perfect. Didn't know about the applicability for the rest of the OS, either. Must be a long-standing convention--I was under the impression that alt was typically used for toolbar shortcuts and something like would be more ctrl appropriate. Either way, good to know!